# How to track the changes of the variable on a low level / TrackedSymbols?

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, tracking

There is a nice option to `Dynamic` or `Manipulate` wrapper functions, where one can specify, which of symbols Mathematica should track.

How does it work and what is underneath this `TrackedSymbols`? Is it possible to implement somewhat like this without frontend? Since Wolfram has an ability to trace the evaluation process using `Trace`, I am wondering is there any low-level functions, which can work like an interruption (similar to SocketListener)

```
(*somewhere in the code*)
EventListener["OnChange":>Symbol, callback];
```

I bet, there is something, but probably undocumented. It should definitely be run on a secondary kernel (which stands for the evaluation).

Moreover, we have a inbuilt debugger, therefore there must be an access to it.

Comment: I would consider the case, when Wolfram Language is used without Mathematica or outside of it as a general purpose language. It would be nice to explore the possibilities of WL, since this functionality was already used in Mathematica. Then, if we have some computations running, one could write OnChange->SocketSend["to other program or websever in the internet"]